Flutter pdf height exceeding in page
I am creating pdf file from dart and requirement are as below,
Page have below widgets,
1. Container
2. Row -- have 2 child and both have TextViews.



When code executed getting below error,

E/flutter ( 3640): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Widget won't fit into the page as its height (985.81) exceed a page height (811.8897637795275). You probably need a SpanningWidget or use a single page layout.

Code are as below,
pdf.addPage(
      pw.MultiPage(
        maxPages: 30,
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat(pageWidth, pageHeight, marginBottom: 30),
        build: (context) {
          return [
            createProfileSection(resume, pdfImage),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 18, 30, 0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: getFirstRow(resume),
                    flex: 4,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: getSecondRow(resume),
                    flex: 6,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ];
        },
      ),
    );


If your content does not fit within a single page, consider using widgets like Wrap or adjusting the flexibility of your widgets. This might involve using Flexible rather than Expanded to allow for more dynamic sizing, or restructuring your layout logic to better accommodate content overflow.

In that case, overflowed data should render on second page

After using Flexible getting error:
Unhandled Exception: Exception: This widget created more than 20 pages. This may be an issue in the widget or the document.

Please try to add margin, I have also facing same issue few months ago I added margin and issue has been resolved.

ok, but where because getFirstRow and getSecond method already have SizeBox and Text combination.
It will be very helpful if you provide sample code or mention where to add margin
